# Translation of できた and それで in this sentences

Tags: translation, parsing

In this sentence:

> お前らは運がいい。今日の俺の試合を見て、**勉強できる機会ができたからな**。お前らは、**それで勉強して**、俺を倒す夢を見続けろ。だが、敵わないけどな。

What is the best literal translation of 勉強できる機会ができたから and それで勉強して
Is できたから saying "Because I'm giving you..."?
and is それで勉強し saying "At that studying" or "While you are studying"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`～ができる` means *to be made/created* or *to form* (intransitive).

> Ice **forms** at a temperature of 32°F.
>   氷はカ氏32度で**できる**.
>   (taken [from here](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/form))

勉強する機会ができた literally means "a chance to study formed", or more naturally, "you've got a chance to learn (from how I played today)".

`それで` in this context literally means "by means of it" or "using it", and それ here refers to the "chance to learn". A less literal translation would be "You guys, take this opportunity and learn from me, and keep dreaming of defating me."

Comment: So does   mean something like "Using this opportunity, study it(the opportunity)"?

Comment: Well we don't say 機会を勉強する at least in Japanese :-) The object of 勉強する here is implied; "the way I play", "my move", etc. That's why I translated it as "learn from me".